# Python 3 Bottle on RPi invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'favicon.ico'

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, bottle

I recently got a raspberry pi and a book to go along with it(Raspberry Pi Cookbook). One of the projects is controlling the GPIO pins on the RPi via a webpage. When I first ran the code after typing it out, I received a bunch of errors so, I tried running the code listed on the books github page:

```
from bottle import route, run
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

host = '192.168.1.8'

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
led_pins = [18, 23, 24]
led_states = [0, 0, 0]
switch_pin = 25

GPIO.setup(led_pins[0], GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(led_pins[1], GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(led_pins[2], GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(switch_pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def switch_status():
    state = GPIO.input(switch_pin)
    if state:
        return 'Up'
    else:
        return 'Down'

def html_for_led(led):
    l = str(led)
    result = " <input type='button' onClick='changed(" + l + ")' value='LED " + l + "'/>"
    return result

def update_leds():
    for i, value in enumerate(led_states):
        GPIO.output(led_pins[i], value)

@route('/')
@route('/<led>')
def index(led="n"):
    print(led)
    if led != "n":
        led_num = int(led)
        led_states[led_num] = not led_states[led_num]
        update_leds()
    response = "<script>"
    response += "function changed(led)"
    response += "{"
    response += "  window.location.href='/' + led"
    response += "}"
    response += "</script>"

    response += '<h1>GPIO Control</h1>'
    response += '<h2>Button=' + switch_status() + '</h2>'
    response += '<h2>LEDs</h2>'
    response += html_for_led(0) 
    response += html_for_led(1) 
    response += html_for_led(2) 
    return response

run(host=host, port=80)
```

When I run the code(sudo python web_control.py) I get a invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'favicon.ico' error. Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 744, in _handle   
   return route.call(**args)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1480, in wrapper    
   rv = callback(*a, **ka)  
  File "web_control.py", line 42, in index    
   response += "  window.location.href='/' + led"
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment
192.168.0.108 - - [29/Dec/2014 21:31:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 740

Traceback (most recent call last): 

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 744, in _handle   
 return route.call(**args) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1480, in wrapper    
 rv = callback(*a, **ka)  
File "web_control.py", line 36, in index    
 led_num = int(led)ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'favicon.ico'
```

Any idea what is going on here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

what does your

```
print led
```

show ?

they say that led is not an int so the error could be from there